# How to copy & paste from Ubuntu VirtualBox guest to Windows host?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, clipboard

I am running VirtualBox 4.1.4 on my Windows 7 laptop, running an Ubuntu 11.10 guest.

I would like to copy text from Ubuntu's terminal and paste it into a file on the Windows host. This doesn't work for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that if you have "Locate pointer" enabled (highlights your pointer when you fit Ctrl), there is a bug in 12.04 that prevents this from working. Switch off "Locate pointer" and it will work. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/9441

Comment: I believe @d3vid is talking about the "Locate pointer" setting in Ubuntu, not in Windows. In Ubuntu 14.04, this setting is found under gnome-tweak-tool; see http://askubuntu.com/a/425498/159361

Comment: Sadly stackexchange doesn't seem to allow me to post an answer since I haven't earn 10 reputation yet... So I'm posting a quick answer here: 1/ On Windows install Git Bash 2/ On virtual box, add a port forwarding on host IP ::1 and port 2222 to the guest IP and port 22 3/ Start the VM 4/ With Git Bash connect to the VM `ssh user@localhost -p 2222` 5/ Use the VM through Git Bash where you can copy/past everything you want

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Start your VM then install Virtualbox Guest Addition

You can find this option under "Devices" on virtual box 4.2 or you can follow the explanations at [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtual-box/22745#22745)

Comment: We have a [how to for installing guest additions here on AU](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtual-box/22745#22745)

Comment: This CD image is not available anymore.

Comment: also you need to enable the shared clipboard under Devices menu on the VM's toolbar.
Devices > Shared Clipboard > [Host To Guest | Guest To Host | Bidirectional]

Comment: Do the same for `Drag'n'Drop` too

Answer (score 122):

Go to VirtualMachine's Settings->General->Advanced->Shared Clipboard (Bidirectional)

Reboot your virtual machine.

for me it solved the problem (it was set on Disabled), I had some machines working some not, so i checked settings in working ones they had bidirectional clipboard. Dont know if this was upgrade issue or... just double check your shared clipboard options.

Hope this helps someone.

VirtualBox V 4.1.20

Comment: how can i paste the text from window to ubuntu server? `Ctrl + Shift + V` does not help

Comment: @ThaiTran I don't know of a way to do this directly. A decent workaround is to ssh into your server from a terminal emulator, and then just paste into the emulator.

Comment: Worked without rebooting the virtual machine (virtualbox 5.0.14).

Comment: Using Virtual Box 5.0.18 and Ubuntu 14.04, the reboot is not required. The essential step is turning on the shared clipboard.

Comment: Do the same for `Drag'n'Drop` too

Comment: Thank you!!! it works!!!

Comment: Worked for me,.. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I had to do four steps:

1. Install Virtual Box extension pack in host

   - http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.28/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.28-100309.vbox-extpack
2. Activate shared clipboard in menu

   - https://askubuntu.com/a/438204/245048
3. Install Virtual Box guest extensions in ubuntu guest

   - `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11`
4. Reboot virtual machine

Comment: That's what worked for me from ubuntu host to ubuntu guest, thanks !

Comment: step 3 was missing and worked for me

Comment: Step #3 lead to boot jam on Ubuntu 17.10, where was previously installed guest additions via sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso

Comment: yeah, It's worked but there is a step #4 - reboot VM.

Comment: @Dee `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` some how fixed my issue, thank you

Comment: @Jason Liu, surprised it still works the same... 3 years old comment. Possible the response steps needs update.

Answer (score 4):

Did you install the required virtual box tools?? (the ones that you should install on guest operating system to gain smooth operation / interaction between the host and the guest)

Comment: Probably not. What tools should I install, and how?

Comment: It is called "Guest additions" as @soekarmana answered.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) if you have access to the Internet.

Comment: Or, alternatively, [pastebin.ubuntu.com](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: A guest user cannot delete a paste? Just pasted some sensitive stuff and found out a second later it can't be deleted. Really frustrated!

Answer (score 3):

In VirtualBox 4.x:

Start the Ubuntu instance, then in the VirtualBox menu at the top of the running instance window, Machine > Settings..., Advanced tab, change Clipboard Sharing to Bidirectional. It's set to Disabled by default for some reason - not clear on why I'd ever want that.

Answer (score 1):

The summary of "Main OS and Virtual OS Integration":

1. Install Vbox Guest Additions
2. Enable Shared Clipboard
3. Enable Drag'n'Drop
4. Enable Shared Folder (optional)

Answer (score 1):

I marked some text from firefox and tried to paste it into a terminal and it didn't work. I had guest additions installed, and also enabled bidirectional copy and paste and it still didn't work, but now I found the reason.

Apparently when I marked the text in firefox, additional information is also stored like the font and style. The terminal can not interpret this, so it doesn't seem to accept it. I pasted the text into a plain text editor (notepad++ in my case) then selected the text again and copied it. Now when I pasted it into the terminal it worked.

So this can also be a reason why copy&paste doesn't work, even if everything is correctly setup.

Using VirtualBox 4.3.12 with Ubuntu 14.04 x64 as the guest.

Answer (score 0):

in recent virtual box follow these instructions :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For VMWare 15, I had to pause / shutdown the machine and go to VM -> Settings -> Options tab -> Guest Isolation

From there you can check / uncheck Enable copy and paste[image]

Answer (score -1):

For some reason I was not able to copy from my WindowsXP VM in VirtualBox to Ubuntu. However, I solved the problem by enabling a shared folder.

You can do that by going to `Devices > Shared Folders > Shared Folder Settings` in the alt menu on the VM window. After you set up a folder in the host, you can access it inside the VM in `My Network Places`:

[image]

Comment: Tried all of the above nothing seem to work  cut-n-paste, scrolling. I am using Win10 host, ubuntu 18.04 guest, VBox 6.1.1