# How do i set CTRL not to show where the pointer is?

Tags: 11.10, cursor

After recently re-installing, i went through every System Setting and choose exactly how i wanted everthing to be.

Except one thing.

I'd never seen the `Show Cursor on CTRL` value before, and wanted to know what it was like. After a while it was simply annoying, whenever i paste of cut in chrome it takes the focus off of the text before i can press `V`.

I have been through eveything in System Settings and can't find it again to disable it.

How do i set `CTRL` *not* to pulse around the cursor?

I will be happy with directions in System Settings, Ubuntu Tweak, or GConf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me awhile to find it as well, its System Settings -> Mouse and TouchPad and then on the first tab under general.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't see it anywhere! Will mark as answer in 7 minutes, won't let me now.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 13.10 I found it only in the packet

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

(german in "Optimierungs-Werkzeug") and there in the Setting for the mouse:

[image: show location of mouse pointer]

And here is the old [german screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USUzr.png) (Hebt die aktuelle Position des Zeigers hervor, wenn die Strg-Taste gedrückt und wieder losgelassen wird.)

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 still the same.

Comment: Would please make an English screenshot instead, You can use `LANGUAGE=en gnome-tweak-tool` .

Comment: good point, didn't know how to open guis in english