# copy from main system and paste in vbox

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy & paste from Ubuntu to Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73059/how-to-copy-paste-from-ubuntu-to-windows)

How can i copy the information from my main Ubuntu system and paste that information in the VirtualBox System ? I have tried with general command like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd>  & <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd>  , But they are not working .is there any way i can achieve that ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open the Vbox Window
   [image]
2. Select your VM
3. Then click on Settings
4. Then under "General" go to the Advanced tab.
   [image]
5. Then on Share clipboard select "Host to Guest" [2nd option, under Disabled]
   [image]
6. Click Accept.

(Don't mind the Spanish, it's the same for all languages)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its not working for me :( . I am running Ubuntu 12.04 as Main and minimal Ubuntu in VirtualBox and its belongs to oracle .

Comment: Try with bidirectional instead.

Comment: actually that was the option already there , i change it to as you suggested . But tried again to that and No progress .:( .

Comment: Note that you can only copy & paste selected text. Binary data or files can not be copied via the clipboard.

Comment: @Takkat Yes i know and i doing text only . Thank you :)

Comment: In my case the steps of this answer did not work until I installed the guest additons on my ubuntu vm. 
I used this tutorial to install it. https://www.nakivo.com/blog/install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox-virtual-machine/ .     


cd /media/user1/VBox_GAs_6.0.8/

sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run