# copy paste not working in virtualbox from Ubuntu [host] to Ubuntu [guest]

Tags: virtualbox

How to copy & paste with VirtualBox from Ubuntu (host) to Ubuntu (guest)?

I installed virtualbox guest edition on Ubuntu [guest] system. But still its not working. If anyone can have some solution then please share it.

Comment: To close voters: This is *not* the same as [that question](http://askubuntu.com/q/73059/22949), where the solution is to install the VirtualBox Guest Additions; the OP here has told us s/he's already done that. **darkshbhatt21**: Does it work if you make sure to keep the program containing the text on the host open? And does it work the other way around--can you copy in the guest and paste the copied text in the host? What version of Ubuntu is running on each, and (if you know) what interface? (For example, are they both running Unity, Unity 2D, Xfce...)

Comment: Host = Ubuntu 12.10, Guest = Ubuntu 12.10, both working Unity and 32-bit, I can copy-paste files from host to guest and vice-versa but I can not copy text, From gedit [on host] to gedit or terminal [on guest]

Comment: Still experiencing the same problem? With Ubuntu 13.10 and latest VirtualBox?

Comment: @Braiam I'm experiencing the problem with 13.04 and the latest VirtualBox (and the latest extensions).

Comment: @Pointy 13.04 is EOL, use 13.10 and test.

Comment: @Braiam Well it didn't work before it was EOL either :) I do need to update however.

Answer (score 3):

Open up the VirtualBox Manager, select your guest machine, and go to Settings. In General, there should be a tab called "Advanced". Make sure "Shared Clipboard" is set to "Bidirectional".

Comment: Similar answer http://askubuntu.com/a/184714/46709

Comment: This is apparently something that needs to be done, but it does not necessarily fix the problem.