# Copying files from Ubuntu guest to Windows host

Tags: virtualbox, file-sharing

I want to transfer files from my Ubuntu (installed on VirtualBox Version 5.1.26) to Windows 7 host. I'm able to copy files from my host to guest using Shared Clipboard but I want to copy the other way round. I already installed Guest Additions as mentioned in [How to copy & paste from Ubuntu VirtualBox guest to Windows host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73059/how-to-copy-paste-from-ubuntu-virtualbox-guest-to-windows-host)

I've been through many other posts on the Internet but none worked for me. I can use WinScp or Putty or any other file transfer applications but that's not what I want, I don't want to use any alternative file sharing software for this.

Comment: Did you make the copy option `bidirectional` in the settings?

Comment: yes I did it but still no use...

Comment: Did you see https://askubuntu.com/questions/366742/how-to-share-the-files-from-host-to-guest-in-virtual-box-host-ubunutu-guest-ubu for shared folders? Alternatively you could use Samba in the host to make a network share which would be accessible from the guest.

Comment: See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders

Comment: @Murphy may be you got me wrong. Please read before claiming duplicate. i want to **copy files from guest to host** not host to guest( in which case obvi shared folders working superb).

Comment: @Takkat yes I've seen that but I need to transfer files from guest to host.

Comment: Shared folders are always bidirectional. Virtualbox needs to have write permissions, and you will have to mount the shared folders with write permissions in the guest. Did you try it out? What did not work?

Comment: @Takkat A shared folder can be read-only.

Comment: @Takkat yes I've mount the shared folders with write permissions and also user is added to `vboxsf`. Any guess what should be wrong? there is no paste option when I right click in the Shared Folder.

Comment: See [screenshot from my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/252865/3940) - we have to **untick read only** of course.

Comment: yes I've read only unchecked and Auto-mount checked.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/a/30446/3940 for causes of errors.

Comment: Ok now that's pretty strange. Files are copied to a new folder that is created within the Shared folder. But the files are denied to copy in the Shared Folder itself with no error!!!!