# How do I copy from the ubuntu 18.04 vm terminal and paste into windows 10?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to copy my ssh key from ubuntu to github and have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.  I've tried using the copy and paste from the edit drop down and also tried this command: `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to copy to my clipboard.  None of these seem to work.  I am new to programming and ubuntu.  I'm unsure of what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy & paste from Ubuntu VirtualBox guest to Windows host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73059/how-to-copy-paste-from-ubuntu-virtualbox-guest-to-windows-host)

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying inside a VM, in some VM's Windows doesn't know that. If you are using Virtualbox, you can't copy something inside the VM and then paste it on Windows. 
But some VM's can do that like Vmware workstation. 
I used both virtualbox and vmware workstation and i've come across with that problem at the time. While virtualbox doesn't allow you to copy-paste from vm to host ; vmware workstation will allow you to copy-paste to host.

If it isn't so crucial you can mail your key to you or you can transfer it via USB. These are the ways i can think of at the moment.

Note: In virtualbox you can create a **shared folder** and that folder will be used on both in guest and host operating systems. You can give that a try.

Comment: VirtualBox has shared clipboard (i.e. you can copy-paste from VM to host and the other way round) but it’s disabled by default. https://superuser.com/questions/42134/how-do-i-enable-the-shared-clipboard-in-virtualbox

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.